# What is the equivalent of angular.isFunction in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular

In angular 1.x we use this [angular.isFunction](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isFunction) function to determines if a reference is a Function. What is the equivalent of that function in Angular 2. Checked in [doc](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/index.html). But did not get anything.

Also please suggest the equivalent functions of [this list](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function) in angular 2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the JS `typeof` operator:

```
typeof x === 'function'
```